# 500 Server Error using Python

Tags: android, python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, internal-server-error

Please bear with me as I am a complete noob and trying to create a database for my app using App Inventor.

According to Google App Launcher, I have successfully created my app. However, when I load mcdougaltextspeak.appspot.com into my browser, I get the following message:

```
Error: Server Error
The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
```

If the problem persists, please report your problem and mention this error message and the query that caused it.

I am following the directions provided on http://appinventorapi.com/program-an-api-python/ and I'm sure my issue is because I am not correctly modifying the default app.ymal file

Here's what I have according to the directions:

```
application: textspeakedtech597
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /images
  static_dir: images

- url: .*
  script: main.py
```

I initially just changed myapp to mcdougaltextspeak, however I got a message that I needed to modify the code for python 2.7 according to this site:

```
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/python25/migrate27
```

This site also included modifications for other things, so I am wondering if my error stems from this. The directions do not make note of modifying any other code. Do I need to modify/add the code that appears on the migrate to python 2.7 page (see above link) and if so where does it go.

My app is stuck without a location to hold data.

Any advice on how to proceed is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does this have to do with android?

Comment: Go here - https://appengine.google.com/dashboard?&app_id=mcdougaltextspeak & check the `Logs`. Also, shouldn't the `app.yaml`'s first line be `application: mcdougaltextspeak` instead of what you've put up?!

Comment: Also you need to show us your index view, otherwise we can't say what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Have you actually created an app on `https://appengine.google.com`?! You need to do that first, then your `app.yaml` should contain the appid that you have created i.e. `application: mcdougaltextspeak` & not what it is in the tutorial.

After you've edited the app as you want, you must then `deploy` the app to the Google App Engine Servers (refer to the GUI deploy). You would get detailed logs when deploying, which would tell if the deployment was successful or not.

After deploying, you can then goto `https://mcdougaltextspeak.appspot.com` & play around with your online app. If you still get errors, check `https://appengine.google.com/dashboard?&app_id=mcdougaltextspeak` for the logs & report them here.